# Blazor application doesn't load the page when hosted in IIS

Tags: iis, blazor

Im trying to deploy my Blazor WebAssembly application (.NET 5.0) to an IIS server. When I load the page I get a HTTP Error 404. With this there is also an API which I use Swagger for. I can load Swagger and also query the API via Postman, its just the Blazor UI doesn't load. WHat reasons could cause this please?

I have installed the .NET Core Runtime Hosting Bundle on the server.
There are no errors appearing in the console
index.html is present in wwwroot folder

If I publish the Blazor application on its own, then the page loads (with errors as the API has not been uploaded). When I publish from the Web API application then the API works but the Blazor doesn't.

Blazor Application

.NET 5.0

Web.config -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AppName.Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
</system.webServer>
```

Program.cs -

```
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });


        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");



        builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ApiAuthenticationStateProvider>();
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IAuthService, AuthService>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<DialogService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<TooltipService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ContextMenuService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ClipboardService>();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
```

Web API -

.NET 5.0

Startup.cs -

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AppTitle API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).EnableDetailedErrors());

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAudience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtSecurityKey"]))
        };

        services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                });

        services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
        {
            opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44326",
                                        "https://localhost:44345")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseResponseCompression();

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"upload")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/upload") 
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "AppTitle API"));

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });

        
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

**Failed Request Trace in IIS**

The only error produced in FRT is -

> 102. -NOTIFY_MODULE_START

ModuleName
AspNetCoreModuleV2

Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER

fIsPostNotification
false

750 ms

Warning
103.  -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS

ModuleName
AspNetCoreModuleV2

Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER

HttpStatus
404

HttpReason
Not Found

HttpSubStatus
0

ErrorCode
The operation completed successfully.
(0x0)

ConfigExceptionInfo

Comment: WebAssemblyHostBuilder is not "Blazor Server". The question is contradicting itself.

Comment: Try to be clear about which Projects you have, how you installed them, what version(s) etc.

Comment: Do you have deployed the application in a subfolder? In that case you need to update the base href in your index.html

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks, misuse of wording. I have expanded in the original post.

Comment: @NicolaBiada theres no sub directory

Comment: Could you please use [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to check the error and logs when your application running on IIS ?

Comment: @HuryShen FRT is in post above. Only 1 warning

Comment: Could you please take a look this [document](https://medium.com/swlh/blazor-handling-404s-with-iis-666920a4a60) and try with the two solutions in it. If you try with the first solution of the document, please edit your rewrite rule according to your application directory but not completely same with what provided by Nicola.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible issues about a 404 deploying a Blazor WASM on IIS is the lack of the URL Rewrite Module.
This module is essential in order to use the routing system of Blazor.

Please refer to the following link for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rewrite-urls-for-correct-routing-1

The **web.config** file for the deployed WASM application should be like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The URL Rewrite module is isntalled. I did notice though when I deployed just the Blazor, the web.config file had some URL rewrite rules. When I deployed from the server, the Web.config had no URL rewrite rules.

Comment: Check my answer, I've added a web.config example for a WASM application.

Comment: Still no luck. I have added my current web.config to the post. I added your bit in to it. Adding the above bit breaks the API as well.